# Rails and FactoryBot

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

I have code into FactoryBot which caused the spec test failed with the following error:

> PG::UniqueViolation: ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique
> constraint "article_types_pkey"   DETAIL:  Key (id)=(10) already
> exists.

```
article_type do
  ArticleType.where(id: 10).first ||
    create(:article_type, id: 10)
end
```

Is it possible that `create` will be called before this query `Article.where(id: 10).first` is finished?

Comment: Your code has a race condition; consider what happens if it's run twice at the same time. Both might find ID 10 does not exist, both will try to make ID 10, only one will succeed. In general, avoid hard coded IDs and instead use some other indication. What are you trying to accomplish with this code, what's special about ID 10? And I don't think this is the problem, but what is `article_type do ... end` doing?

Comment: And any other process could be making an ArticleType and happen to create one with ID 10 between the where and create.

Comment: Why/How are you creating an `ArticleType` by setting the id. `id` is usually an incremental primary key generated by the database upon insert of the row. Also as a pure aside `ArticleType.where(id: 10).first` can be changed to `ArticleType.find(10)`

Comment: This code is from spec tests. So I need ArticleType with specific id. I'm not sure that race condition is possible under spec tests.